# custom keyword highlighted as todo in vi

Tags: vim

Starting with vim and love that it highlights todo comments. Around here, however we use a custom keyword (first initial last initial todo: abTODO) so it's easy to grep for todos that apply to a specific person.

I'd love to add mine as a keyword that vi picks up and highlights along with todo, fixme and xxx.

[In vim, how do I highlight TODO: and FIXME:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097259/in-vim-how-do-i-highlight-todo-and-fixme) seems to apply, but using the following does not work:

```
syn match   myTodo   contained   "abTODO"
hi def link myTodo Todo
```

**UPDATE**

In my .vimrc I have the following 3 lines (as suggested):

```
syntax enable
syn match myTodo "\<\l\{2\}TODO\>"
hi def link myTodo Todo
```

That is a lowercase L, not 1. However abTODO is still not being highlighted at all.

Comment: That's very strange. Do you have a filetype set (`:set ft`)? If so, it might be better to add the lines to the relevant syntax file, or to $HOME/.vim/after/syntax/FILETYPE.vim.

Answer (score 3):

Try this match:

```
syn match myTodo "\<\l\{2\}TODO\>"
```

Explanation:

- `\<` matches the beginning of a word
- `\l\{2\}` matches precisely two lowercase letters
- `TODO\>` matches the string `TODO` at the end of the word

Your highlight command is fine at it is. I don't think the `contained` option is necessary here.

Comment: I keep seeing \1\2 instead of \l\2 (mistaking L for one).

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me. Is there something else I'm missing? If I had a fresh vimrc what should be there?

Comment: You still need your line "hi def link myTodo Todo", and as pydave notes, it's a lower-case "L", not a number "1".

Comment: As explained in the updated question, that's what I have to no avail.