# VIM: TODO highlight makes text disappear

Tags: vim, putty

In Putty, when VIM highlights the text TODO or FIXME the highlighted colour is such that I cannot even see the text! I have tried to set `background=light` but that did not help, and in any case I like my dark (unmodified) background. I have read [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097259/in-vim-how-do-i-highlight-todo-and-fixme) which addresses TODO highlighting problems, but I cannot seem to find the solution.

The server is CentOS 5.x with VIM 7.0. Other than my own personal .vimrc file nothing can be changed there. I am connecting using Putty on Windows XP SP3. I do have admin access to the Windows machine, but it is not mine and I cannot do anything drastic to it (such as install Debian like I want to). I can do whatever I like to my own user profile on the Windows box, though.

Comment: `Todo xxx term=standout ctermfg=0 ctermbg=3`

Comment: What is your $TERM set to before launching vim?

Comment: Thanks, Randy. `echo $term` gives me `xterm`.

Comment: I assume you mean `echo $TERM`.  I'm quite stumped if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, I did mean `echo $TERM`. I have Ctrl-6 mapped to Caps Lock in VIM and for some reason that doesn't work in Firefox!

Comment: In your colorscheme, change the `Todo` line to `Todo term=none ctermfg=0 ctermbg=3`.